# Partial derivative vs Total derivative

Tags: field-theory, notation, differentiation

This is essentially a follow up to my question [here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/242484/) since I seem to have some difficulties regarding the differences between partial and total derivatives.

Consider a Lagrangian density

$$\mathcal{L}=\frac{1}{2}\partial_\mu\phi\partial^\mu\phi-\lambda\phi^4$$

with $\phi=\phi(\vec{x},t)$.

From this we obtain a Hamiltonian

$$H=\frac{1}{2}\displaystyle\int d^3x\left(\pi^2 +(\partial_i\phi)^2+\lambda\phi^4 \right)$$

I can write this as $H+H_0+V$ with $H_0=\frac{1}{2}\displaystyle\int d^3x\left(\pi^2 +(\partial_i\phi)\right)^2$

Now I have 
$$\frac{d}{dt}O=\frac{\partial}{\partial t}O+\{O,H \}$$

Set $O=H$. It is clear that $H$ has no explicit time dependence - it's time dependence appears only through $\phi$ and $\pi$. So $\frac{\partial}{\partial t}O$. Furthermore, since $H$ Poisson commutes with itself I then have $\frac{d}{dt}O=$.

Now, if I set $O=H_0$, I still have $\frac{\partial}{\partial t}H_0=0$ by the same reasoning, but $H$ and $H_0$ do not Poisson commute, so I can NOT say $\frac{d}{dt}H_0=0$

Is this correct so far?

Now set $\lambda=0$ so $H=H_0$ and I have a Noether current $j^\mu=\partial^\mu$ corresponding to invariance under $\phi\rightarrow \phi+\alpha$ for some constant $\alpha$. This is where things are getting fuzzy.

Noether's Theorem tells me $\partial_\mu j^\mu=0$ when the fields are on-shell. But the spacetime coordinates only appear in $j^\mu$ through the fields. So naively I would expect to be able to write $\partial_0 j^0=0$, which is not true. So what gives?

Now integrating $\partial_\mu j^\mu=0$ over some spacetime volume we have

$$\displaystyle\int d^3x \partial_0 j^0 + \displaystyle\int d^3x \partial_i j^i =0$$

Some books, eg Greiner, pull the $\partial_0$ outside the integral and rewrite it as

$$\frac{d}{dt}\displaystyle\int d^3x j^0 + \displaystyle\int d^3x \partial_i j^i =0$$

The second term then vanishes by Stoke's theorem assuming the fields fall off sufficiently fast on the boundary, leaving me

$$\frac{d}{dt}\displaystyle\int d^3x j^0=0.$$ The question here is how did a partial derivative become a total derivative?

Comment: The $\partial_\mu$ is meant as the partial derivative of the function $j(x^0,x^1,x^2,x^3)$, not of the function $j(\phi,\pi,t)$. The Noether current is a *Lagrangian*, not a Hamiltonian object, you must not apply the Hamiltonian notion of total/partial time derivative to it. The partial becomes a total time derivative because $\int j^0(x^0,\vec x)\mathrm{d}^3 x$ doesn't depend on anything other than $t=x^0$ anymore, so there is no difference.

Comment: @ACuriousMind Ah right, indeed even in Greiner they have $j=j(x)$ but I guess that slipped past me. As for the second point, I see it now. In $\int d^3x \partial_0 j^0(x)$ the derivative acts first, so the partial is necessary since we have dependence on all spacetime coordinates. But when the integral acts first the partial becomes a regular derivative since we've integrated out all but the t dependence. Right?